# How to properly unit test code inside of a Python function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

How can I unit test variables/values that are inside a function?

This is a rather basic question about unit testing (I am using pytest) that is I want to make sure all my code behaves as expected.

There must be a proper way to do that, but I didn't find out. As of yet, I try to split up my code in as many functions as possible to get as many return values as possible that I can test. But I am not able to test inside those functions.

Here I can only test if the return value `interp_function` is working as expected, but in no way to test the rest of the code.

```
def multidim_interp_function(grid = None, max_error_in_mm=1,
                         max_error_in_deg=1):

    def interp_function(array_of_pts):
        fct_list = create_interp(grid)
        max_error = [max_error_in_mm]*3
        if len(grid) == 6:
            max_error.extend([max_error_in_deg]*3)
    return np.column_stack([error*fct_list[i](array_of_pts) for i,error in enumerate(max_error)])

return interp_function
```

Comment: Generally, you don't unit test the internals of a function.  You treat it as a black box, and test that you get the output that you expect for the inputs you provide - you don't care _how_ the function produces its results, as long as they are correct.

Comment: Functions are the smallest unit that you can break your code into. It hardly makes sense to want to test “inside” functions. You want to test *the function*, **not its implementation.** You want to test whether your function returns the expected result given known input; you don’t want to test *how* it does it, because the *how* may change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to test the *implementation* of your function. If you wrote `foo = 'bar'` inside your function, then you don't need to test whether `foo` correctly has been assigned the value `'bar'`; you can just expect that to work. With unit tests you want to be one step *more abstract*. You want to check whether your function `multidim_interp_function` returns the correct results given some known input. Treat the function like you'd treat other functions in Python: you wouldn't write a unit test to figure out how `max()` works internally, instead you'd write a test asserting that `max(3, 4)` returns the value `4`.

Not only is it impractical to test the "internals" of a function, it's that the internals of a function *may change*. If you're writing your unit tests and you figure out you have some bug in your code, then you're going to change your code. Or you may later come back and refactor the internals to make them more efficient, or to deduplicate some code in your module, or whatever. You wouldn't want to rewrite your unit tests each time. So you shouldn't write your unit tests to be too specific. Your unit tests should test the *public interface* of the function (arguments and return values), so you can assure that this interface doesn't change (i.e. the function continues to behave the same) even if you move some code around. If through your unit test or otherwise you figure out that there’s some misbehavior inside the function, then you can step in with a debugger and confirm each single statement one by one to find where an issue is.

To get into the right mindset, try [Test-Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), in which you write your tests firsts, essentially deciding on how the function *should* behave, and then you implement the function internals, all the while being able to test that your implementation conforms to the expectation.

Comment: Are you familiar with Zed Shaw's 'Learn Python the Hard Way'? In chp 47, he suggests an exercise in automated testing, talking about unittests. It confuses me that his test_ functions do not correspond 1:1 to the functions he tests, as I understand the concept unittest from reading about it most places. Yes I also see others argue that it is nonsense to "only" test functions in isolation like that. What is your thinking about that? Does it represent unittest vs. integration test? Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think you need 1:1 tests corresponding to functions. But that depends on the functions you’re testing. If each single function is so complex that you have many many different input-output scenarios to test, then you may easily have many unit tests for a single function. But at that point, you should probably simplify your function. And when you have simpler functions, it makes less and less sense to test them at all; and you’ll have unit tests which focus more on scenarios than individual functions. As long as your code has good test coverage, anything works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want your function to behave the same and so, results should be predicted. You don't want to test internal state of your function, but rather the output.

```py
def my_calculus(divise, multiply):
    def inner(value):
        return value * multiply / divide
    return inner

calculus = my_calculus(2, 4)

@pytest.mark.parameterize("function,value,expected", [
    (calculus, 2, 4),
    (calculus, 5, 10)
])
def test_my_calculus(function, value, expected):
     assert function(value) == excepted
```